# $location changing the path but not picking up .html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have some code like this:

```
    if(result.data.authenticated === false) {
        //need to send to unauthoirzed page. 
        $location.path('/unauthorized');
    }
```

and when it hits I see my url change to:

```
/#/unauthorized
```

but it's not displaying my HTML page that I have defined here:

```
 .when('/unauthorized', {
                templateUrl:'partials/unauthorized.html',
                controller:'unauthorizedController'
            })
```

just stays on the original page.

Comment: Please add your hole `$routeProvider` code.

Comment: Rather than using the `$location` service, use the `$window` service thus: `$window.location.href = '/unauthorized';`

Comment: Can you show the full code of the first snippet?

Comment: take a look at this question and its answers it might be good help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794115/using-window-or-location-to-redirect-in-angularjs#answer-24794152

Answer (score 0):

This is a full example of AngularJs routing with authorizing. Hope this helps you

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
  ]);

  window.routes = {
    '/': {
      templateUrl: 'app/visitor/visitor.html',
      anonymous: true
    },
    '/index': {
      templateUrl: 'app/visitor/visitor.html',
      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
      anonymous: true
    },
    '/lu/:mt?/:tab?/:id?': {
      templateUrl: 'app/user/user.html',
      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
      anonymous: false
    }
  };

  app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    for (var path in window.routes) {
      $routeProvider.when(path, window.routes[path]);
    }
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

  app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    for (var path in window.routes) {
      $routeProvider.when(path, window.routes[path]);
    }
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

  app.run(function($rootScope, toastr, sessionService, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
      for (var i in window.routes) {
        if (next && next.hasOwnProperty('$$route') && next.$$route.hasOwnProperty('originalPath') &&
          next.$$route.originalPath.localeCompare(i) == 0) {
          if (!window.routes[i].anonymous && !sessionService.getUserAuthenticated()) {
            toastr.error('Access not found');
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/');
          } else if (window.routes[i].anonymous && sessionService.getUserAuthenticated()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/aa/xx/ff');
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });

})();
```

Answer (score -1):

to test if the route updated successfully, in `unauthorizedController` controller add log or debugger to test if the router changed or not, and replate `templateUrl` with `template` and see the result