# How to download an xlsx in angular from express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am generating an `xlsx` file based on some user input in `express`. The info is submitted via a `post` request and I wanted to return the content of the file via `res.download(...)`.

If I do that I get "garbage" in the `data` field of my `ajax` response.

I tried to prompt a download using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514509/how-do-you-serve-a-file-for-download-with-angularjs-or-javascript) solution, but the content is still "garbage".

This is my angular controller:

```
$scope.generateSoldGoodsReport = function() {
        reportService.generateSoldGoodsReport({
            startDate: $scope.startDate,
            endDate: $scope.endDate
        })
        .then(function(report){
            var blob = new Blob([ report ], { type : 'application/xlsx' });
            $scope.url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
        })
    }
```

and here is my service:

```
generateSoldGoodsReport: function (dates) {
    var deferred = $q.defer()

    $http.post('/api/secure/generateSoldGoodsReport', dates)
                        .then(function(response){
                            deferred.resolve(response.data)
                        })
        return deferred.promise
    }
```

and here is my server side code:

```
sendFileResponse = function (res) {
    return function (err, fileDetails) {
        if (err)
        {
             res.json({
                 error: 1,
                 message: err.message,
                 detailed: err.errors
             })
         }
         else
         {
             res.download(fileDetails.path + '/' + fileDetails.fileName)
         }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up using a solution where in a `post` request I generated the report and when the response was sent to the client I made a `get` request to a predefined place where the generated report was stored. I don't like this solution because I use two requests instead of one.