# Downloading Mp3 file from remote. Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to download a mp3 file from the remote url using node js. For that I am using the following code. But It doesn't work (File that downloading having 0 bytes only its not playing once it downloaded).

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = "http://play.publicradio.org/rivet/d/podcast/marketplace/segments/2015/09/28/mp_20150928_seg_01_64.mp3";
var dest = "2.mp3";
var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log("res "+response);
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
        console.log("File download Completed");
    });
}).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors

});
```

Comment: Try  http://www.hacksparrow.com/using-node-js-to-download-files.html

Comment: I had a similar issue. You can check out how I solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987847/how-to-download-an-xlsx-in-angular-from-express

Comment: @Chetan :same problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is that `http` doesn't follow redirects.
You can use the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm module that does it by default to avoid handling headers yourself.

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
  request = require('request');

request
  .get('http://foo.com/bar.mp3')
  .on('error', function(err) {
    // handle error
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('2.mp3'));
```

Comment: I was trying to save the `response` via `fs.writeFile()`, which damaged the file. You answer is simple and good. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi `request` npm module is now deprecated