# How to show save file dialog in Safari?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, safari, pdf-generation

I need help. I have an angular app and by using DocRaptor want to generate PDF and save it as file. But I cant trigger the dialog to save file in Safari with any method what I have found on Stack Overflow. Those methods open file in current browser tab and replace site html or open file in new tab. No one cant shows the dialog. Here the examples what I have already tried to use. Environment MacOS - EL Capitan. Safari 9.0.3

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16514741/2309309) #1

```
var content = 'file content for example';
var blob = new Blob([ content ], { type : 'text/plain' });
$scope.url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
```

Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/4554/). Shows file in current tab. Replaces site. But works in Chrome.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269227/2309309) #2

```
<a target="_self" href="mysite.com/uploads/ahlem.pdf" download="foo.pdf">
```

Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdrv/n6kp5bsr/). Doesnt work at all in Safari. Works in Chrome.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541187/2309309) #3

```
<a class="btn" ng-click="saveJSON()" ng-href="{{ url }}">Export to JSON</a>
```

and

```
$scope.saveJSON = function () {
            $scope.toJSON = '';
            $scope.toJSON = angular.toJson($scope.data);
            var blob = new Blob([$scope.toJSON], { type:"application/json;charset=utf-8;" });           
            var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                        downloadLink.attr('href',window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                        downloadLink.attr('download', 'fileName.json');
            downloadLink[0].click();
        };
```

Example [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541187/2309309). Shows the file content instead of document's html.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339233/2309309) #4

```
function download(text, name, type) {
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = name;
}
```

Example [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339233/2309309). Replace document with file content in Safari. Works in Chrome.

And similar [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30832210/2309309) #5

```
function download(text, name, type) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = name;
    a.click();
}
```

Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdrv/5u19fo48/1/). Doesnt work at all in Safari. Works in Chrome.

Also I have tried to use libraries like:
[FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) - It opens file in Safari instead of document. So you should click Cmd+S. [Example](https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/). 
If we use type 'pplication/octet-stream' the name of file will be unknown or there was be an error 'Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted'. [Issue](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/12#issuecomment-47247096).

Second library [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) - doesnt work in Safari at all. [Issue](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify/issues/64).

Angular library [nw-fileDialog](https://github.com/DWand/nw-fileDialog) - instead of save as it shows choose file. [Issue](https://github.com/DWand/nw-fileDialog/issues/3).

DocRaptor has own [example](https://docraptor.com/documentation/jquery) with jQuery.
Example with angular in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdrv/u36pgp84/). It works in Chrome but in Safari example doesnt work be cause of error with SAMEORIGIN

> Refused to display 'https://docraptor.com/docs' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

But if we reproduce it on server and change url on 'https://docraptor.com/docs.pdf' it works and open file in new tab and automatically download the file so you cant choose a folder and after download user see white empty screen tab in browser. If we specify form target="_self" it will work perfect, but console will have an error 'Failed to load resource:'.

I will appreciate any help with this problem. 
Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) file for this:

```
// Buffer can be response from XMLHttpRequest/Ajax or your custom Int32 data
function download(buffer, filename) {
  var file = new Blob([buffer], {
    type: 'application/octet-stream' // Replace your mimeType if known
  });
  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
    var converted = e.target.result;
    converted.name = filename;
    converted.webkitRelativePath = filename;

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = converted;
  };
  fileReader.onerror = function(e) {
    throw new Error('Something is wrong with buffer data');
  };
  fileReader.file = file;
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

It basically uses filebuffer and download that as an iframe content. Make sure to hook correct mime type so that safari security system will recieved analyse filetype.

Comment: Thanks!  Any ideas how to set the filename for the downloaded file?  Currently in Safari OSX 10.0.3 it shows up as "Unknown".  I tried `iframe.title = filename;` and `iframe.name = filename;`, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, Solution #2 would be the answer, but the download attribute [does not yet have cross-browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

So you have to use a `<form>` to create the download. As you noted, DocRaptor's [jQuery example](https://docraptor.com/documentation/jquery) uses this technique.

The SAMEORIGIN error is actually because JSFiddle is running the code in an iFrame with their origin settings. If you run this straight from your Angular application, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, form work in 2 ways which I have written in footer =) "it works and open file in new tab and automatically download the file so you cant choose a folder"

Comment: That issue might not be solvable, you shouldn't need the ".pdf" though.