# How to download a text file based on a generated String using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, file, download

I'm trying to get AngularJS to trigger a file download when a user clicks on a button.

The file that should download has to contain data that is generated during the script execution, so the text file's content should be built from a basic string in AngularJS.

How do I implement this?

Here is some mockup code on how I imagine this would work:

```
var fileContent = 'foobar';
$scope.download = function() {
  filedownload.run(fileContent, 'filename.txt');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you serve a file for download with AngularJS or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514509/how-do-you-serve-a-file-for-download-with-angularjs-or-javascript)

Comment: [Angular File Saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver) is a good polyfill for less modern browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve this you have to create an a tag in your HTML:

```
<a download="content.txt" ng-href="{{ url }}">download</a>
```

Controller:

```
var content = 'file content for example';
var blob = new Blob([ content ], { type : 'text/plain' });
$scope.url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
```

And to enable the URL:

```
app = angular.module(...);
app.config(['$compileProvider',
    function ($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|blob):/);
}]);
```

Source:
[How do you serve a file for download with AngularJS or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514509/how-do-you-serve-a-file-for-download-with-angularjs-or-javascript)

Comment: Use `aHrefSanitizationWhitelist = /^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|blob):/`. For more information see [AngularJS sanitizeUri.js source code line #9](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/sanitizeUri.js#L9).

Answer (score 2):

In simple cases, you can create a link with a [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs):

```
var fileContent = 'foobar';
$scope.download = 'data:text/plain;base64,' + btoa(fileContent);
```

And then use it in your HTML template:

```
<a href="{{download}}">click here to download</a>
```

You may need to adapt the MIME type, depending on your string.

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting approach. While this does generate a valid link, the download gets rejected in chrome due to an unsafe link error.
For explanation:
I want to create a vCard file in Angular to download and this is not the right solution.
Do you have a follow up idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Chrome rejects it only when the site is localhost? Other than that, I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: I actually found a solution myself now. It's basically the same idea as yours

Comment: See [AngularJS $compileProvider API Reference -  aHrefSanitizationWhitelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#aHrefSanitizationWhitelist)